# Does Docker (Compose) assume a default health check command with CMD-SHELL?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was adapting the [Docker Compose example from Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/docs/reference/setup/install/docker/docker-compose.yml) to set up a default cluster and have stumbled over this health check config which I don't understand:

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
  interval: 1s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 120
```

I can guess that this command checks for the existence of the file at `config/certs/es01/es01.crt`. But how does it do so with the script

```
[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]
```

?

More specifically: is some unix command inferred before the `-f` option? And what are the square brackets for?

Comment: `[ -f xxxx ]` is a shell conditional that checks if a file exists. More conditionals here: https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: Thanks @HansKilian. I definitely am a bash beginner as the domain name implies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is a shell command; it is the same as [**test**(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  Checking on a MacOS and Ubuntu system, in both cases there is a `/bin/[` with an ordinary executable of that name in a normal search-path directory.

In your example, `[ -f filename ]` is the same as `test -f filename`, which returns true (exit code 0) if the file exists.

In a broader Bourne shell context, `if [ -f filename ]; then ...; fi` isn't special syntax.  It runs `[`, and if that command returns true (exit code 0) then it runs the `then` block.  You can put any command in the `if` statement and not just `[`.

Comment: Thanks, David. I am a Windows native visiting strange countries, so I appreciate you finding time to spell out the basics for me :)